# Input in modal dialog from another component

Tags: vb.net, dialog, keyboard, screen, modal-dialog

i wrote a screen keyboard for a application in visual basic .net, which i try to use to wirte in the textbox of a modal window. The problem here is that my keyboard is blocked by the modal window, too. So i cannot send any information to the window.

Dose someone know whether there is a possibility to except a window being blocked by a dialog or has an other idea how to get information from the keyboard window to the modal window?

Thank you in advance for any answeres

Answer (score 0):

I tried it myself and it worked fine. Here is what I did:

Create a new Windows Project in Visual Studio and add 2 Forms and a Module

In Form1, add a label and a button

In Form2, add a textbox and a button

In Module1 add a Public String variable to hold the string that will be passed from Form2 to Form1

```
Module Module1
    Public strMessage As String = ""

End Module
```

Go back to Form1, and double click Button1 to write the code that handles its click event

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim popUp As New Form2
        popUp.ShowDialog()
        Label1.Text = strMessage    
End Sub
```

Now in Form2 double click Button1 to write its Button.Click event handling

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        strMessage = TextBox1.Text    'Save the string that the user has input before unloading the form
        Me.Close()

End Sub
```

That should do it. I tried it and the text from Form2 appeared in the Label of Form1

Comment: ok, but my problem is that once the blocking window is opened i can not manipulate the label on it by hitting a button on an other component, because the other component is blocked. what i need is to block everything but my keyboard, so i can send information to the dialog when i hit a button on it.

Comment: That does not make any sense. If you want to change something on a form that is not Modal then why did you open it modal?

Comment: I want to open it modal to block the running application. But the application contains my on-screen keyboard too what means that it is also blocked and i cannot hit any button on it. the modal dialog contains a textfield for entering a password. I want to be able to enter the password with my on-screen keyboard, what currently is blocked. So it would be nice to block everything except my on-screen keyboard if this is possible in any way